# Solving the ordinary differential equation: $y' = (x + y)^2.$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$y' = (x + y)^2$  solving for first order differential equation, What should I do to express $y'$ as a function of $y$? I let $y=xv$ but I couldn't solve.

Answer (score 3):

I'll give you a hint: $(x+y)'=(x+y)^2+
1$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Set $z=x+y$ to get:
$$z'-z^2-1 = 0$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $v(x)=y(x)+x$. We have:

$v'(x)=y'(x)+1$

$(y(x)+x)^2=(v(x))^2$, so we get equation:

$v'-1=v^2$ and now it's easy to solve.